# Concatenate same array(number) from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, row, concatenation

It's a bit hard to explain here but I'll try my best to include all related information. You can ask me if you don't understand.

[image]

Above is the data I got and I wish to combine the same number (e.g 2016) to be displayed as shown below.

[image]

This is my code.

```
<?php
    $years = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(event_date) as years, DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%b') as months from news WHERE status<>'deleted' and status<>'draft' ORDER BY years DESC");

    while($page=mysql_fetch_array($years))
    { ?>
        <div class="date">
            <div class="year"><a href="<?php echo $sys_domain; ?>/news/index.php?year=<?php echo $page['years'] ?>&month=<?php echo $page['months'] ?>"><?php echo $page['years']; ?></a></div>

            <div class="month"><a href="<?php echo $sys_domain; ?>/news/index.php?year=<?php echo $page['years'] ?>&month=<?php echo $page['months'] ?>"><?php echo $page['months']; ?></a></div> 
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This is my database
[image]
[image]

May I know how to combine the year? I used "GROUP BY" but cannot, it hides the 2nd row of data. Or should I compare the value and combine it? But I have no idea how to do this. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this coding...

You are get result value and apply in your html content.

```
     <?php
        $years = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(event_date) as years, DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%b') as months from news");

        $result = array();

        while($page=mysql_fetch_array($years))
        {

            $year = $page['years']; 
            $month = $page['months'];

            $result[$year][] = $page['months'];

        }   

        if(isset($result)) {

        foreach($result as $key=>$year_array) { ?>

           <div class="year"><a href="<?php echo $sys_domain; ?>/news/index.php?year=<?php echo $key; ?>&month=<?php echo $month; ?>"><?php echo $key; ?></a></div>
           <?php 
           if(isset($year_array) && count($year_array) != 0) { 
                foreach($year_array as $month) { ?>

                     <div class="month"><a href="<?php echo $sys_domain; ?>/news/index.php?year=<?php echo $key; ?>&month=<?php echo $month; ?>"><?php echo $month; ?></a></div> 

            <?php } }
         } }   ?>
```

Comment: I got the error message --> Function name must be a string

Comment: what line display the error and post the updated coding ?

Comment: sorry that is print_r($result); I have updated coding

Comment: Opps. I also didn't realized about the print_r. Now I got Array ( )

Comment: check your query return result.

Comment: I think you put something wrong. Should be `$months = $page['months'];` instead of  `$year = $page['years'];`. So the database is `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%b') ='".$months."'`. After amended, I got Array ( [11] => Array ( [0] => Feb ) [12] => Array ( [0] => Jan ) [13] => Array ( [0] => Jun ) )

Comment: Yes, the info is correct. Array
(
    [2016] => Array
        (
            [0] => Feb
            [1] => Jan
        )

    [2015] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jun
        )

)
But how to display it without array? Sorry, I'm a beginner please bear with me.

Comment: Glad to help, Can you upvote and accpet this answer ?

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved my problem. Sure upvote and accept the answer for you. And I have amended you code. There is a small error. Kindly see that.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this:

```
$years = mysql_query("SELECT YEAR(event_date) as years, GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%b') SEPARATOR '<br />') as months from news GROUP BY YEAR(event_date)");
while($page=mysql_fetch_array($years))
{ ?>
    <div class="year"><?php echo $page['years']; ?></div>
    <div class="month"><?php echo $page['months']; ?></div>  <?php 
} ?>
```

Comment: So sorry because I didn't include my code completely. I need to filter the information by clicking the month. So my code is shown above(edited).
When I click the month to filter, my URL reflected `index.php?year=2016&month=Feb<br%20/>Jan`

Comment: Check whether the code fetches the required format. Html you can bind According to your requirement